# Unable to replace space with comma in powershell script

Tags: powershell

In database, I have stored value like: a,b,c
When I fetch and pass it to powershell script as parameter and print, it changes to: a b c
I have tried replacing string using `$param1.replace(' ',',')` and `$param1 -replace '\s',','`, but it is not working.
Please help me resolve this.

Comment: If you make `$param1.getType().FullName`, you probably see something like `string[]`, where `[]` means that it is array of values. This means that those 3 values are passed as array ov values, and spaces are added only to output. You can iteract through like `foreach ($val in $param1) { write-host "Parameter element: $_" }`

Comment: When I give $param1.getType().FullName, it is showing as Object[] @filimonic

Comment: That means you have array of objects (the most abstract class). So, same for that case: your `$param1` is collection (`[]` means that), and it is not string. Run this: `foreach ($val in $param1) { write-host "[$($_.getType().FullName)] $($_)" }` and you`ll see contents of your collection line-by-line.

Comment: My mistake in code: `foreach ($val in $param1) { write-host "[$($val.getType().FullName)] $($val)" }`

Comment: [System.String] a [System.String] b [System.String] c. How do I concatenate this? @filimonic

Comment: Just $concatResult = $param1 -join ','

Comment: It is working now.Thanks a bunch! :) @filimonic

Answer (score 0):

I've found somethinw that would help:

```
PS > ("this is test").Replace(" ", "-")
this-is-test
```

source: https://www.itechguides.com/powershell-replace/

Comment: Great! But **how** does it help? Could you please [edit] the answer and explain how this helps? Just some code and a link could be considered a link-only answer. So please expand and at least quote/paraphrase the most relevant info from the linked source. Make sure to follow the referencing guidelines found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: I have tried using .Replace() It is not working.